# javascript setTimeout or jquery delay - neither are working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

I have a `div` like this

```
<div id="sale">
    ........
</div>
```

and I tried to use both

```
$('#sale').delay(3000).slideDown(500);
```

and

```
setTimeout(sale(), 3000);

function sale() {
    $('#sale').slideDown(500);
}
```

but neither of them are working. The jQuery delay says `$('#sale').delay()` is not a function while the `setTimeout` way says useless `setTimeout` call (missing quotes). If I add double quotes around the `sale()` call, it just says "Sale is not defined".

Why won't either of these work?

All I'm trying to do is make a div appear 3 seconds after the page is loaded.

Comment: `setTimeout(sale, 3000);`, not `setTimeout(sale(), 3000);`

Comment: The `.delay()` method was added in `jQuery 1.4`. What version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case of `setTimeout` you're simply doing it wrong.

```
setTimeout(sale(), 3000); // will call sale and use the RETURN value in the callback but sale returns undefined
```

You need to pass in a function:

```
function sale() {
    $('#sale').slideDown(500);
}

setTimeout(sale, 3000); // just pass in the reference to sale()
```

Other possibility:

```
// no difference in this case
// Note: if it were obj.sale() then you would need to do this version
//       otherwise sale() will get called with the this set to window
setTimeout(function(){sale()}, 3000)
```

And last but not least:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#sale').slideDown(500); }, 3000);
```

Comment: @Matthew I know, fixed it, just habit since I always end up with the need of a that when I use setTimeout ;)

Comment: alternatively you could just put the animation inside the anonymous function

Answer (score 5):

You need to be in a queue for `delay()` to work.

```
$('#sale').queue(function() {

   $(this).delay(3000).slideDown(500).dequeue();

});
```

[See it.](http://jsfiddle.net/98xhb/)

[Patrick Dw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) has informed in the comments you don't need to be in a `queue()` if your next method chain is an animation. See his [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/Uts7t/).

Comment: delay() can't be the *first* element of an animation chain?

Comment: @AndreKR - Yes it can. This answer is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/Uts7t/

Comment: @patrick dw I could of *sworn* I recently read you need to be in a `queue()` for `delay()` to work... Oh well. Is this a recent jQuery development?

Comment: @Catish What does `alert(typeof jQuery)` say?

Comment: @alex - Well you do, but animations are added to a queue automatically. If you were to call something like `.css()` after `.delay()`, it would need to be manually queued.

Comment: @patrick dw Thanks for teaching me something. +1 to your comment (and answer, if you post one). Oh, and I wouldn't say this answer is *wrong*, just unnecessarily verbose. :)

Comment: @alex - Well ok, I'll say it was wrong in its implication (as evidenced by the first comment), but yes, the code did work. :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(sale, 3000);
```

Before, you were passing `setTimeout` the return value from `sale`.  This passes the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution it seems that jQuery is not even loaded.

In the second code you have to do `setTimeout(sale, 3000);` (omit the parentheses) because with them you are calling setTimeout with the *return* of `sale()`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Argh, I wasn't sure... lost the 50/50 chance. ;)

Comment: jquery is loaded. i just didn't post that part

Comment: It's ok to omit that part but here it's possibly the problem. Does a simple `$('#sale').slideDown(500);` without delay work?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout("sale();", 3000);
```

Comment: Bad idea - this internally evokes an `eval()` type function. Just pass `sale` as the argument.

Comment: Another possible issue with this is that it isn't uncommon to define functions within the `.ready()` handler. If that's the case, `sale` would be inaccessible to the `setTimeout` which attempts to evaluate the string in the global context.